# How to prefund treasury pallet?

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet-treasury

I want to prefund treasury pallet in chain_spec `GenesisConfig`. Is this possible? Someone please give some advice. [Github](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MVP_Lending_Pool/blob/58f45173c81878a9e56ec9d0ab899c2d19ce1e26/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L250)

Answer (score 1):

Use Subalfred https://github.com/hack-ink/subalfred/tree/main calculate your treasury account and fund it here https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MVP_Lending_Pool/blob/58f45173c81878a9e56ec9d0ab899c2d19ce1e26/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L212.